# Laravel multilevel relationship with dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I need to create a function that should select only posts which have is_public = 1 and approved = 1. But only for guests. For login users, it should show all posts.
The issue that I have self-relationship in my model when categories trying to find subcategories and also posts linked to the category and all subcategories.

The function below is doing what I need: BUT

```
$categories = PostCategory::whereNull('parent_id')->with(
        ['posts' => function($q) {
                $q->where('is_public', 1);
                $q->where('approved', 1);
            }])->with(['categories.posts' => function($q) {
                $q->where('is_public', 1);
                $q->where('approved', 1);
            }])->with(['categories.categories.posts' => function($q) {
                $q->where('is_public', 1);
                $q->where('approved', 1);
            }])->with(['categories.categories.categories.posts' => function($q) {
                $q->where('is_public', 1);
                $q->where('approved', 1);
            }])->with(['categories.categories.categories.categories.posts' => function($q) {
                $q->where('is_public', 1);
                $q->where('approved', 1);
            }])->orderBy('order')->get();
```

For any new level of the category tree, I need to add a new WHERE clause:

```
categories.categories.categories.(UNLIMITED categories).posts
```

And I know that is stupid and inaccurate. There should be another way to get 'public' and 'approved' posts in every category and every subcategory.

That is my model:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_category', 'category_id', 'post_id');
}

public function categories(){
    return $this->hasMany(PostCategory::class, 'parent_id');
}
    
public function childrenCategories(){
    return $this->hasMany(PostCategory::class, 'parent_id')->with('categories');
}
```

Of course, I can do next:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_category', 'category_id', 'post_id')->where('approved', 1)->where('is_public', 1);
}
```

But in this case, it will not show all posts to the login users.
Please help me to build the right and accurate code for that function.
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is authenticated in the post function

```
if(Auth::check()){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_category', 'category_id', 'post_id');
    }else{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_category', 'category_id', 'post_id')->where('approved', 1)->where('is_public', 1);
    }
```

Comment: It will work in this case but imagine that I'll have different types of options. 
For example 'public', 'approved', 'deleted', post 'created after April 5th', and a lot of other filters, and user can select any or two option of all of them. In this case, I don't want to create a different IF ELSE in the model. I just need to build the WHERE clause and send it to the model. And I'm sure that it's possible. I just can't find the right way. (((